# Does the impact location of small stones on car windshields significantly affect the likelihood and extent of a break?

Tags: material-science, simulations

Is the center of the windshield much less stable than the locations closer to the edges in this regard? Is there a negible difference? Does it result in different types of damage?

Any info is appreciated (and would help settle a discussion among friends about this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objective of the rubber windshield mounting gasket is to not only seal it against rain leaks but also to furnish some "give" so that if the windshield glass shape does not exactly conform to the shape of the windshield frame, the frame will not apply large stresses to the glass. On some cars, the shapes of the frame and the glass are poorly matched, in which case the frame will try to twist or bend the glass despite the presence of the rubber gasket.

It is possible for the stresses imposed by the frame to overcome enough of the residual compressive stress built into the windshield during its manufacture so that the impact of a thrown rock will cause the glass to break in tension, in that location where the stresses are worst. The impact resistance of the windshield will hence vary according to the distribution of stresses imposed by the "tweaked" frame.

In some cars (certain models of British sports car) the body of the car flexes while being sharply maneuvered and this flexure stresses the windshield and can cause it to crack, especially if the windshield has previously been chipped by a rock impact. In this case too, the location of the chip will determine the resulting fragility of the windshield, which will also be a function of exactly how the body flexure stresses are spatially distributed across the expanse of the glass.